# How to populate dataframe from dictionary in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, google-natural-language

I am trying to perform entity analysis on text and I want to put the results in a dataframe. Currently the results are not stored in a dictionary, nor in a Dataframe. The results are extracted with two functions.

df:

```
ID    title    cur_working    pos_arg         neg_arg                             date
132   leave    yes            good coffee     management, leadership and salary   13-04-2018
145   love it  yes            nice colleagues long days                           14-04-2018
```

I have the following code:

```
result = entity_analysis(df, 'neg_arg', 'ID')

#This code loops through the rows and calls the function entities_text()
def entity_analysis(df, col, idcol):
    temp_dict = {}
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        id = (row[idcol])
        x = (row[col])
        entities = entities_text(x, id)
        #temp_dict.append(entities)
    #final = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id', 'name', 'type', 'salience'])
    return print(entities)

def entities_text(text, id):
    """Detects entities in the text."""
    client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
    ent_df = {}
    if isinstance(text, six.binary_type):
        text = text.decode('utf-8')

    # Instantiates a plain text document.
    document = types.Document(
        content=text,
        type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)

    # Detects entities in the document.
    entities = client.analyze_entities(document).entities

    # entity types from enums.Entity.Type
    entity_type = ('UNKNOWN', 'PERSON', 'LOCATION', 'ORGANIZATION',
                   'EVENT', 'WORK_OF_ART', 'CONSUMER_GOOD', 'OTHER')

    for entity in entities:
        ent_df[id] = ({
            'name': [entity.name],
            'type': [entity_type[entity.type]],
            'salience': [entity.salience]
        })
    return print(ent_df)
```

This code gives the following outcome:

```
{'132': {'name': ['management'], 'type': ['OTHER'], 'salience': [0.16079013049602509]}}
{'132': {'name': ['leadership'], 'type': ['OTHER'], 'salience': [0.05074194446206093]}}
{'132': {'name': ['salary'], 'type': ['OTHER'], 'salience': [0.27505040168762207]}}
{'145': {'name': ['days'], 'type': ['OTHER'], 'salience': [0.004272154998034239]}}
```

I have created `temp_dict` and a `final` dataframe in the function `entity_analysis()`. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056171/how-to-build-and-fill-pandas-dataframe-from-for-loop) explained that appending to a dataframe in a loop is not efficient. **I don't know how to populate the dataframe in an efficient way**. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854728/python3-4-dataframe-from-dictionary) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops) are related to my question but they explain how to populate a Dataframe from existing data. When I try to use `temp_dict.update(entities)` and return `temp_dict` I get an error:

> in entity_analysis
>       temp_dict.update(entities)
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I want the output to be like this:

```
ID          name                  type                salience
132         management            OTHER               0.16079013049602509 
132         leadership            OTHER               0.05074194446206093 
132         salary                OTHER               0.27505040168762207 
145         days                  OTHER               0.004272154998034239
```

Comment: Have you just changed your question from "Currently the results **are not** stored in a dictionary" to "Currently the results **are** stored in a dictionary" ? That's a pretty big change to your original question, I think it's fair it should be rolled back since there's already an answer.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create a list of lists via your `entities` iterable. Then feed your list of lists into `pd.DataFrame`:

```
LoL = []

for entity in entities:
    LoL.append([id, entity.name, entity_type[entity.type], entity.salience])

df = pd.DataFrame(LoL, columns=['ID', 'name', 'type', 'salience'])
```

If you *also* need the dictionary in the format you currently produce, then you can add your current logic to your `for` loop. However, first check whether you *need* to use two structures to store identical data.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have found a solution. I have created multiple dictionaries, because I had to iterate over the text and the words. Apologies for the confusion.